# Mathematica can't export $\sqrt{}$

Tags: bugs, pdf-format

**Fixed in version 10.1.0**

---

It looks like version 10 can't export to pdf correctly with square root.

For example:

```
Export["~/Downloads/11.pdf", 
 ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Frame -> True, Joined -> False, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(x\)]\)", "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(y\)]\)"}]]
```

I get

[image]

with the square root sign on the vertical axis magically disappeared. Is this a bug or because some fonts missing on my computer?

Could you confirm this?

I'm using version 10.0.2 on OS X 10.10.1.