# Math diacritics go missing when exporting graphics

Tags: export, bugs, pdf-format, workaround

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 or 10.0.2 and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

Take this example plot:

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(_\)]\)"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I export it to PDF, the overbar in $\bar x$ goes missing.

```
Export["~/Desktop/test.pdf", plot]
```

[image]

This is with Mathematica version 10.0.2 on OS X and looks like a bug to me.  **Is there a workaround?**  All I need for now is a workaround.

Comment: There have been a few Qs like this since V10 came out. The problem typically effects the y axis rendering of fraction boxes, subscript boxes, etc etc It seems to be an important bug that is yet to be fixed. I'm not aware of a workaround but have not searched rigorously. @Jens seems to be the guy to ask for PDF related fixes so he might have a solution.

Comment: Related (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69275/mathematica-cant-export-sqrt/69279#69279)

Comment: Try RotateLabel -> False

Comment: in v10.1.0 OSX the overbar is exported but it seems not well centered on the top of x ...

Answer (score 1):

Seems to export well (v10.0.2 OSX) this way :

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", 
    Rasterize[Style[OverBar[Pane@x], 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
     RasterSize -> 200]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me (v. 10.0.0 on Mac), exported.  You might want to use the **Basic Writing Assistant** template for the bar.

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(_\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

Might a workaround be:

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(x\), \(_\)]\)"}]
```

Comment: it is broken in subsequent versions

Comment: The problem is present in 10.0.2 though and I do not have a 10.0.0 installer around.  Also, 10.0.0 has a number of other bugs that affect my work.  That said it would of course be possible to use 10.0.0 only for exporting but not actually generating the figures.