# SciDraw: Vertical axis not copied into Word 2013 (Windows 7, Mathematica 10.1 SE)

Tags: plotting, packages, scidraw

Using the [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu) package, I created a multi-panel figure of list plots with labels along both the $x$ and $y$ axes. But when I copy/pasting the result into Word, the vertical axis labels are nowhere to be seen. Why?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use SciDraw, so I can't help you with it directly, but have you tried to export your figure to a file (e.g. EMF if you are on Windows), instead of using the clipboard? I have generally had poor results in the past in copy / pasting directly from *Mathematica* to Word.

Comment: This might not be related to SciDraw.  Unfortunately, as Marco says, copying and pasting to Office applications on Windows is not reliable.  It uses the EMF format, which cannot represent all Mathematica graphics accurately and also seems to be buggy.  Things to try: 1. export to EMF using the `Export` command (*not* by right click and Save Graphics As...; for some strange reason that might produce different results).   2. If that doesn't work, then export to a bitmap format like PNG.  I wrote about how to export to size [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12).  ...

Comment: ... Try it like this:  `fig = Figure[...]` so `fig` contains the Graphics object, then export as `Export["file.png", Show[fig, ImageSize -> 5 cm], ImageResolution -> 300]`. It is important that the image size is specified within `Show` and not `Export`, while the resolution is specified within `Export` and not `Show`. I don't know why ... I just know it from experience. 3. If you are preparing figures for publication (for a journal), the best thing may be to export to PDF and not insert them in Word directly. Word is notorious for destroying figures (I'm struggling with Word for Mac right now)

Comment: Actually there's one more thing I just remembered.  Please include your operating system version and Mathematica version in the question.  There was a bug in some 10.x version (don't remember which) on Mac where rotated text disappeared when exported to PDF. If you are on Mac, this may be the problem.  Upgrading to Mathematica 10.3.1 will fix it.

Comment: Or maybe I'm wrong and I was remembering [this problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75755/12) instead?

Comment: assume you have office, try pasting into powerpoint, then copy/paste to word.  In both cases do a right click paste-as enhanced metafile.  It might also be useful to see if you can reproduce the issue w/o scidraw, or perhaps create a minimal example and post the `FullForm` of the graphic.

Comment: If all you want is a static graphic cut from Mathematica into Word, and you are using a Windows 7 or later system, the easiest approach might be to use the [Windows snipping tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-snipping-tool-capture-screen-shots#1TC=windows-7)